# Equivalent of ActionSheet Plugin for Phonegap in Android?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

iOS ActionSheet plugin for phonegap:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ActionSheet

Is there a Android equivalent? (preferrably that uses the same js interface)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a plain Javascript interface that will run on Android too. Maybe check out this?

https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-actionsheet#javascript-interface-iosandroid

Comment: Well that's only going to work if I have the native code in the Android project included. I can't find that.

Comment: You can't just import this javascript file into your www folder? https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-actionsheet/blob/master/www/ActionSheet.js

Comment: I did that, but I assume there is native code that it is executing (that's th way the iOS version works).

Comment: Strange the plugin.xml file is referencing to a src/android/ActionSheet.java file. But it's nowhere to be seen...

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it without any native file and it doesn't do anything of course.

Comment: OH, where did you see that reference (I need the whole line). Maybe it's standard with cordova and I have to do is add the line.

Comment: nvm, deadend; seems like he was planing to add that and never did? im seeing that there may not even be an equivalent of ActionSheet in android.

Comment: Anyways...maybe try to find a jQuery ActionSheet plugin? Or just build it yourself. https://github.com/hiroprotagonist/jquery.mobile.actionsheet

Comment: Yeah I might settle for a non-native implementation. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

This is very good and for Android, iOS and WP

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-actionsheet